# cleveref not capitalized at the start of a sentence

Tags: cleveref

It seems cross-references generated by the cleveref package are always in lowercase by default, no matter whether they're used to start a sentence or not. Is there a way to get cleveref to respect the capitalization rules of the English language?

Minimum working document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\label{section1}
\cref{section1} shows that cleveref ignores capitalization when it is used in the beginning of a sentence.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that "section 1" is generated as lowercase, even though it starts a sentence and should therefore be capitalized.

Comment: Just like you capitalize words at the start of a sentence, write `\Cref` to get an upper case reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote [emphasis added]:

> It seems cross-references generated by the `cleveref` package are *always* in lowercase by default...

Not quite. The `cleveref` package provides two main groups of user-level macros:

- `\cref`, `\crefrange`, `\cpageref`, `\cpagerefrange`, and `\namecref` -- to be used in the middle or at the end of a sentence, and
- `\Cref`, `\Crefrange`, `\Cpageref`, `\Cpagerefrange`, and `\nameCref` -- to be used at the start of a sentence.

Summing up: to create a cross-reference at the start of a sentence, be sure to use `\Cref`, not `\cref`.